# displaying a positive result instead of negative

Tags: java, math, difference

I am creating a java program that will ask the user to input 2 integers then it will display the sum, difference and product. I need help for how to make the difference not show a negative result for example if the user inputs a smaller number first such as 2 and 5 I want the program to display 3 instead of -3

Here is the Java Code

```
/**
 * @author Robbie Ramirez
 * Unit2
 * This program will calculate the sum, difference, and product of two integers
 */

//Scanner for user input

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Integer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        //Ask the user to input two integers
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Input two integers");

        // Stored the input integers 
        int num1 = sc.nextInt(); 
        int num2 = sc.nextInt();

        // Integers sum, difference, and product calculation 
        int sum = num1 + num2;
        System.out.println("\nThe sum is " + sum);

        int difference = num1 - num2;
        System.out.println("\nThe difference is " + difference);

        int product = num1 * num2;
        System.out.println("\nThe product is " + product);
    }
}
```

Comment: please edit to show your code and add the correct language tag

Comment: What's wrong with "If a > b, then return a-b, otherwise return b-a"?

Comment: Oh you are right, this is my first time programming so I am still figuring out things.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Math.abs(x) where x is an int to convert negative to positive and if the difference is positive nothing will happen

Answer (score 1):

Just use method Math.abs(), the implementation is like this

```
 int difference = Math.abs(num1 - num2);
```

Its will work and remove negativity